# Creating own object powershell

Tags: powershell

I ve got a script which get each folder and get name,filescount,size of each folder.

Size with measure-object doesn t work.

My first try using my own object to handle this([pscustomobject]).

May I integrate a command (measure-object) in an object ?

```
Get-ChildItem d:\ -Directory -Recurse -Depth 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|
ForEach-Object{

    [pscustomobject]@{
        FullName  = $_.Fullname
        FileCount = $_.GetFiles().Count
        size=measure-object -sum -property length


                }


} | sort -Property filecount -Descending
```

Thks ,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be using the result from [`.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-getfiles) twice, first for getting the total file count and the second time to get the sum of the file's `Length`, hence I would advise you to store the result of that method call in a variable for further manipulation.

To get the folder size, you can either use [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-sum(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-int64)))):

```bash
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Directory -Recurse -Depth 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | & {
    process {
        $files = $_.GetFiles()

        [pscustomobject]@{
            FullName  = $_.FullName
            FileCount = $files.Count
            Size      = [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int64[]] $files.ForEach('Length'))
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property Filecount -Descending
```

Or, if you want to use [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.2), the `Size` property would be:

```bash
Size = ($files | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
```

Lastly, if you want to do a recursive search per folder, you can target the [`.GetFiles(String, SearchOption)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-getfiles(system-string-system-io-searchoption)) using `AllDirectories` for [SearchOption Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=net-6.0):

```bash
$files = $_.GetFiles('*', [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately folders don't actually have a size (Windows is just kind enough to find out for us when we check the properties of it)

So in your script you need to get all child items of the current iterations folder and measure their combined size.

```
Get-ChildItem d:\ -Directory -Recurse -Depth 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        FullName  = $_.Fullname
        FileCount = $_.GetFiles().Count
        size = (Get-Childitem -Path $_.Fullname -recurse | measure-object -property length -sum).sum
    }
} | sort -Property filecount -Descending
```